# Android styles aren't applied

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm trying to style my application with custom styles. However, I am facing a problem when on install of application the styles aren't applied, then if I change something (anything) in the styles and compile it again (reinstall not uninstall followed by install) it applies all the styles. But as you understand this isn't an intended experience for users.

What could cause such a strange behavior?

UDATE:
The api is from 13 to 17.

I'm getting this:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

As you can see the styles aren't applied to this dialog. This also happens to other activities.

Comment: would you mind providing something more specific?

Comment: could you show me your manifest.xml file?